# how to update a table from a JSON loaded object using peewee ORM on python

Tags: python, json, sqlite, peewee

```
from schema import db, CustomerTable as GF
db.connect()

#this works
query = GF.update(Priority=88).where(GF.CustomerID==1)
query.execute()
```

can someone help me with this please? The above code works fine in updating an sqlite database. The bottom doesn't.

```
#this doesn't work and help needed...

#JSON string
customers = '{ "name":"john john", "mobile":12345678, "email":"john.doe@gmail.com"}'
pycustomers = json.loads(customers)

# print(pycustomers["name"])
for keys in pycustomers:
    print("This is the key: ", keys, "\t\tThis is the value: ", pycustomers[keys])
    query = GF.update({keys: pycustomers[keys]}).where(GF.Mobile==pycustomers["mobile"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the keys of the JSON dict correspond to fields on the model, you can just pass the data right in:

```
customers = '{ "name":"john john", "mobile":12345678, "email":"john.doe@gmail.com"}'
pycustomers = json.loads(customers)

# print(pycustomers["name"])
nrows = (GF.update(pycustomers)
        .where(GF.Mobile==pycustomers["mobile"])
        .execute())
```

Docs that may be helpful:

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.update
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#atomic-updates